# extrapolate data from xsl produced document

Tags: xml, xslt

As Question title. I've a text document produced by using an XSL stylesheet, having the xsl "schema" there is a simply way to extrapolate the data from the text document.

I.E.

```
|<xsl:text> Cod. ABC. </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$CodABC"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$piuCodici"/><xsl:text>  Cod.DEF </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$CodDEF"/><xsl:text>   </xsl:text>|
```

I need to extract back $CodABC, $piuCodici, $CodDEF. Is there any java or python or javascript library that can do that giving the XSL stylesheet?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the original `$CodABC`, `$piuCodici`, `$CodDEF` did not contain any spaces, then it should be relatively simple to parse the result and extract the values between known strings. This has nothing to do with XSLT. There is no generic way to reverse an XSL transformation.

Comment: The document structure is complex, very long and with conditional sections for this reason I was searching for a library that extract the values for me having the XSL.
Thank you for the comment.